# Using Datediff result in other column

Tags: php, mysql, date, datediff

I'm trying to get a number of days of multiple results between dates and insert into a table from the same table.
I have a table with the following:

```
|ID|openDate  |closeDate|resultDays|
|1 |2018-05-05|2018-10-10|158        |
|2 |2018-10-07|2018-10-12|5          |
 ------------------------------------
```

This result I got in the mysql terminal, with the following structure

```
mysql> update newdbtable set resultDays = datediff(closeDate, openDate);
```

How could I populate the resultDays column of every date using php?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. What's wrong with the update statement? are you attempting to generate  new rows? or update existing rows?

Comment: This is an example.
If I have 100 rows I would have to do everything manually.
What I want is to carry out the process and add the number of days automatically.
In this case, I left the values ​​as an example of what I did in the terminal, but in php I can not make it work.

Comment: @banana Your existing query should update all the records in the `newdbtable`. But what if `openDate` and/or `closeDate` value changes in the future. You will have to again update the `resultDays` column. Depending on your MySQL version, you can rather use [Generated Columns](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/)